# sed & protobuf: need to delete dots

Tags: regex, bash, sed, proto

I need to delete dots using sed, but not all dots.

```
- repeated .CBroadcast_GetBroadcastChatUserNames_Response.PersonaName persona_names = 1
+ repeated CBroadcast_GetBroadcastChatUserNames_Response.PersonaName persona_names = 1
```

Here the dot after `repeated`, (`repeated` also can be`optional | required | extend`) should be deleted

```
- rpc NotifyBroadcastViewerState (.CBroadcast_BroadcastViewerState_Notification) returns (.NoResponse)
+ rpc NotifyBroadcastViewerState (CBroadcast_BroadcastViewerState_Notification) returns (NoResponse)
```

And here delete dot after `(`

It should work on multiple files with different content.

---

Full code can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SteamRE/SteamKit/7640dfe40323d4b64e0eb562b43a6108535b9ef4/Resources/Protobufs/steamclient/steammessages_broadcast.steamclient.proto)

Comment: Whats the problem?

Comment: You haven't explained any logic of what the command should do, for your example it could just be `sed 's/\.//g'`.

Comment: When people ask you to explain, it means your question isn't clear (usually). Please update your Q rather than responding in comments. You can always include a comment "see revised Q above, thanks for your help" ;-). Good luck.

Comment: Why not sed -n 's/\(.NoResponse\)/\(NoResponse\)/p' ?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: pluse-uno for updating your Q. Now it makes some sense. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A perhaps simpler solution (works with both GNU `sed` and BSD/macOS `sed`):

```
sed -E 's/([[:space:][:punct:]])\./\1/g' file
```

<sup>In case a `.` can also appear as the *first* character on a line, use the following varation:

`sed -E 's/(^|[[:space:][:punct:]])\./\1/g' file`</sup>

The assumption is that any `.` preceded by:

- a whitespace character (character class `[:space:]`)

  - as in:  `.`
- or a punctuation character (character class `[:punct:]`)

  - as in: `(.`

should be removed, by replacing the matched sequence with just the character preceding the `.`, captured via subexpression `(...)` in the regular expression, and referenced in the replacement string with `\1` (the first capture group).

---

If you invert the logic, you can try the simpler:

```
sed -E 's/([^[:alnum:]])\./\1/g' file
```

<sup>In case a `.` can also appear as the *first* character on a line:

`sed -E 's/(^|[^[:alnum:]])\./\1/g' file`</sup>

This replaces all periods that are *not* (`^`) preceded by an alphanumeric character (a letter or digit).

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this, [agc's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44911416/8254934) solution works too, but this seems more prettily

Comment: @morphchallenge: I'm glad to hear it; I just added a simpler solution that inverts the logic. On a meta note: You don't have enough reputation yet, but keep in mind that once you reach 15 points, you can - in addition to _accepting_ an answer - _up-vote_ additional answers that you also found helpful (such as agc's in this case).

Comment: @agc: Thanks; I didn't think it was necessary to handle the case of a line-initial `.`, given the sample input, but I've updated the answer to show how to handle that case too, if needed.

Comment: Another wrinkle:  input `" . "` returns a blank, and `" ... "` returns `" .. "`.

Comment: @agc: That's straying pretty far from the sample data. Since we don't have a formal specification and the answer works as described, I think I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming only the leading `.` needs removal, here's some *GNU* `sed` code:

```
echo '.a_b.c c.d  (.e_f.g) ' | 
sed 's/^/& /;s/\([[:space:]{([]\+\)\.\([[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]_.]*\)/\1\2/g;s/^ //'
```

Output:

```
a_b.c c.d  (e_f.g)
```

Besides the `.`, it checks for two fields, which are left intact:

1. Leading whitespace, or any opening `(`, `[`, or `{`.
2. Trailing alphabetical chars or also `_` or `.`.

Unfortunately, while the `\+` *regexp* matches one or more spaces *et al*, it fails if the `.` is at the beginning of the line.  (Replacing the `\*` with a '*' would match the beginning, but would incorrectly change `c.d` to `cd`.)  So there's a kludge...  `s/^/& /` inserts a dummy space at the beginning of the line, that way the `\+` works as desired, then a `s/^ //` removes the dummy space.

Comment: @morphchallenge : while you can only accept 1 answer to your Q, you can upvote answers that you find helpful ;-) . I'm glad you got two good answers . Good luck.